How to Simplify Google Tag Manager Setup for Complex Sites?
I’ve been working on setting up tracking for a fairly complex website using Google Tag Manager. While GTM is a powerful tool, I often find the setup process to be time-consuming, especially for sites with dynamic structures or multiple tracking needs.
The main challenges I face are:
Identifying what needs to be tracked across the site (especially custom events).
Designing a cohesive tracking plan that covers everything without redundancy.
Efficiently deploying the tags and triggers in GTM without errors.
I recently experimented with an approach that automates a lot of this workflow:
Automatically scans the website to identify key tracking points.
Generates a tracking plan using AI, saving hours of manual planning.
Deploys everything to GTM in one click.
It’s helped streamline the process for me, but I’m curious if anyone else has faced similar challenges and found effective solutions. Are there any tools, strategies, or scripts you recommend to simplify GTM setups?
If anyone’s interested in learning more about the approach I tested, feel free to ask in the comments, and I’d be happy to share my experience.

Using AI for large implementations like this is never a good idea. It often makes mistakes with larger contexts. For now, the publicly available LLMs are only good for writing short functions that don't rely on anything outside of them. And you still have to re-read what they generated.
Now when you say "complex site", it would be nice to specify more details. Most complex sites rarely use GTM as a TMS for the first-party tracking. They normally either use enterprise-level TMSes like Adobe Launch or Tealium, or they go for in-house solutions.
On larger sites that do use GTM, the real question is not how you structure your GTM, but how you synchronize and govern ten analytics developers working in the same TMS. While GTM's version control is not too bad, people often go for git integrations. But still, GTM's the only TMS that limits the size of the compiled lib. So you should be very careful about how that team of developers works with the container. Juniors tend to generate a lot of wasteful tags, variables and whatnot.
If you're more or less a sole developer doing GTM implementations for larger sites, the classical way to go about it is standardization of your DL layout for the FE developers to implement. That way you can just use more or less the same GTM container on all sites.
